# $exp(-\frac{\sigma^2}{4a^2}) \leq \frac{a}{\sigma}$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that $exp(-\frac{\sigma^2}{4a^2}) \leq \frac{a}{\sigma}$ for $\sigma > a$? 
I tried to proof it with the function $f(x)=-exp(-\frac{\sigma^2}{4a^2}) + \frac{a}{\sigma}$. But this didn't work out as I hoped it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that
$$\frac{\sigma}{a}\,\exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2}{4a^2}\right)\leq 1 $$
for $\sigma>a$ is the same as proving that:
$$ f(x)=x\, e^{-x^2/4} \leq 1 $$
for $x> 1$. By computing $f'(x)$ we have that $f(x)$ takes its maximum over $\mathbb{R}^+$ in $x=\sqrt{2}$, hence:
$$ \forall x\geq 0,\qquad x e^{-x^2/4} \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{e}} < 1.$$